# Stopwatch running slow - Javascript / Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a stopwatch that I am running as an ember.js controller, and it is running just a tad slow, so over time it falls behind. Trying to determine how to best speed this up to time accurately. Not sure if this is being caused by browser lag, or if the system isn't happy running this process at this speed.

```
//timer.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  state: 'reset',

  tick: 0,
  seconds: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  lapTime: 0,

  isResetState: Ember.computed.equal('state', 'reset'),
  isRunState: Ember.computed.equal('state', 'run'),
  isPauseState: Ember.computed.equal('state', 'pause'),
  isLapState: Ember.computed.equal('state', 'lap'),

  incrementTick(startDate) {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    if (this.get('isRunState') || this.get('isLapState')) {
      this.incrementProperty('tick', currentDate.valueOf() - startDate.valueOf());
      Ember.run.next(this, 'incrementTick', new Date());
    }
    if (this.tick > 999) {
      this.set('tick', 0);
      this.incrementProperty('seconds', 1);
    }
    if (this.seconds > 59) {
      this.set('seconds', 0);
      this.incrementProperty('minutes', 1);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    start() {
      this.set('state', 'run');
      this.incrementTick(new Date());
    },

    stop() {
      this.set('state', 'pause');
    },

    reset() {
      this.set('state', 'reset');
      this.set('tick', 0);
      this.set('seconds', 0);
      this.set('minutes', 0);
    },

    hold() {
      this.set('lapTime', this.get('tick'));
      this.set('state', 'lap');
    },

    continue() {
      this.set('state', 'run');
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: your code seems to assume that incrementTick gets called exactly 1000 times per second - though, I'm not 100% sure your code does assume that - it seems overly complicated for what it actually does - but perhaps that's because of ember.js

Comment: It's not embers problem. It is pc architecture itself. You need [real-time system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) for this to work. I would suggest reading some articles about how game loops should be made.